# How to print next line after refresh?

Tags: go

I want to create a `/health` that displays each line of a song. I'm trying to display the next line of the song after refresh of the page but my code below doesn't work and I don't know what's missing.

**Expectation**

It should return different lines from the song after each refresh like this.

```
➜ curl http://localhost:8080/health
It starts with one thing

➜ curl http://localhost:8080/health
I don't know why

➜ curl http://localhost:8080/health
It doesn't even matter how hard you try
```

**Reality**

```
➜ curl http://localhost:8080/health
It starts with one thing

➜ curl http://localhost:8080/health
It starts with one thing

➜ curl http://localhost:8080/health
It starts with one thing
```

Here are some lines from `main.go` and `testlib.go`.

**testlib.go**

```
func GetLine() func() string {
    n := 0
    lines := strings.Split(readFile(), "\n")
    length := len(lines) - 1

    return func() string {
        nextLine := lines[n]

        if n == length {
            n = 0

            return nextLine
        }

        n++
        return nextLine
    }
}

func Handler(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
        log.Println(r.URL.Path)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}
```

**main.go**

```
func health(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    line := testlib.GetLine()

    fmt.Fprintln(w, line())
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/health", testlib.Handler(health))
    log.Printf("http://127.0.0.1:8080 is now listening.")

    if err := http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Every request you call the `health` function, which creates a new closure in `GetLine`. To untangle put everything in a single file and remove those extra nesting. PS: if you were slightly more successful maintaining the state between requests - your code would still be invalid due to a data race (mutating `n++`).

Comment: As a sidenote, if two users try to do request one after the other, what's the expectation. Will the first request by second user get the second line ? If not you may need to start use session

Answer (score 0):

Because `n` is local variable, it's will always re-declared with the value is `0` whenever you call that `GetLine()` function. May be you need a global variable to save value of last line :D

Comment: No need for a global variable - closures with a locally scoped variable could work just fine